# Add new field in db with django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to let users to add new field.
How to add new field in database from user or admin interface (except to use South)?

Comment: Adding new field dynamically from users looks bad. Just make table with rows representing the fields and then add the new row

Comment: In http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter10.html you can learn to do it.

Comment: I must add new column with using interface.

Comment: Try to explain why you want this behavior, because for me it makes little sense. There are probably a more suitable solution to your problem.

Comment: In web2py you can edit the code from within the admin, and web2py is designed to ALTER TABLE when the model is altered. But syncdb is not designed for that: change the code in a model.py that doesn't match the DB and you get a 500.

Answer (score 0):

[The Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) show how to run raw sql. So if you connect to the db as a user with the correct privileges you can run `ALTER TABLE` statements.

HOWEVER you REALLY REALLY have to sanitise your inputs properly otherwise you may as well just put the root password on the front page of your site.

And all that said... there's almost certainly a better approach to solving your problem. You should describe in more detail what you're trying to do.

Comment: Lets suppose we implement a perfect code to run the "ALTER TABLE" without any risks. Still the Django models are unable to read the new columns created, so we also want to auto-edit models.py to expose the DB. And restart the webserver to apply the code changes. Errors happen, so we want also some track of DB editions, maybe a subdir in each app called "migrations" and a file describing each ALTER. Later on you would want a tool to revert an ALTER.

You end re-inventing South, but worst.

Comment: Well I don't think it's a good idea either.  That said, the OP didn't say he needed to access the new columns via the ORM. So he got an answer, but I'm hoping he'll explain what he's trying to do so a better answer can be given.